# Ubuntu does not boot after bad shutdown

Tags: startup

I recently swapped from Windows7 to Ubuntu 11.10 due to problems with my Windows.

Ubuntu worked great for a few days with no problem, This morning I ran out of battery and the laptop shut down. I rebooted it and now it just displays an error message ( black screen with coding commands) it doesn't even go onto the purple screen anymore.

Any help on this would be much appreciated..

Ps: would installing Ubuntu again make any difference?

Comment: What error message are you getting ?

Answer (score 3):

Reinstalling Ubuntu would most probably fix this problem. But in the event that happens you can do several steps. I recommend, if you want to fix the problem the first step is to run **fsck** from a LiveCD.

1. Insert the LiveCD of Ubuntu and when you get to the Desktop open a terminal.
2. In the terminal type `sudo fdisk -l` to see all the partitions/hard drives you have. One of them is your Ubuntu system. It should look something like **/dev/sda1** / **/dev/sdb1** ....
3. Assuming you found the one you are using (Let us say /dev/sda1) do the following: `sudo fsck /dev/sda1`. It should start looking for problems in the partition like orphans and such.Most of the time this solves this. I have seen it happen sometimes in not only laptops but desktops also. After this there is no need for anything else.

Now if you are not worry about the content or have already done a backup just reinstall Ubuntu, the LiveCD should give you the answer to "Reinstall Ubuntu" while executing the installation program from the LiveCD.

Answer (score 1):

First try:

```
Ctrl+c
```

and then:

```
Alt+Ctrl+F1
```

Is it possible now to login (at least in text mode)?